# Нужны ли в этих предложениях запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

1. Местный паренек по имени Фенни, охотно согласился послужить проводником не очень частому в тех местах иностранцу.
2. Угостили, чем богаты.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

1.Местный паренек по имени Фенни охотно согласился послужить проводником не очень частому в тех местах иностранцу.

ИЛИ:Местный паренек, по имени Фенни, охотно согласился послужить проводником не очень частому в тех местах иностранцу

По имени Фенни - приложение.Пунктуация возможна двоякая, в зависимости от наличия или отсутствия пояснительного оттенка и соответствующей интонации при чтении.Как, например, в этих случаях:Маленький чернявый лейтенант, по фамилииЖук, привёл батальон к задним дворам той улицы...(Симонов);Пригласили врача-специалиста по фамилии Медведев.

2.Угостили  чем богаты.Запятой нет, потому что чем богаты - один член предложения - дополнение.Угостили чем? чем богаты (кое-чем, скудно).На правах фразеологизма, который можно заменить одним словом. Было бы придаточным предложением, если бы было в главной части соотносительное слово: Угостили всем, чем богаты.

Answer (score 0):

~1. здесь лучше без запятых. Обороты с "по имени" обычно не считаются уточняющими, поскольку содержат имя собственное.

~2. Нет, не нужна. Это единое по смыслу выражение, является одним членом предложения.

> *§115. Сравнительный оборот §114. Цельные по смыслу выражения*
>
> > Запятая не ставится перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в
> >     составе неразложимых сочетаний,

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm

Домашние задания мы обычно не делаем, но поскольку вас ввел во искушение предыдущий отвечальщик, даю свою версию. Больше этого делать не буду.

Comment: И доказать сможете "неразложимость сочетания"?

Comment: Нет, я не занимаюсь доказательством очевидного.